# Fast computation of inertia tensors in Python

Tags: python, performance

I need to perform a very fast computation of [inertia tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) in [Python](https://www.python.org).

The problem is as follows:

Let `xyz` be a [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org) Array of shape: `(samples, atoms, 3)` that describes the `3` cartesian coordinates of each `atoms` in each `samples`.

The `atoms` in each sample must be splited into a set of molecules. *I need the inertia tensor of each molecule in every sample*.

Each molecule contains `n` atoms and they are ordered in such way that they are grouped together. That is:

```
   numpy.array( numpy.split(xyz, atoms/n, axis=1).shape )
```

returns an array of shape: (number of molecules, samples, atoms per molecule, 3), where the first index runs over the molecules.

Notes:

- *It is very similar to the problem solved* [here](https://github.com/mdtraj/mdtraj/blob/master/mdtraj/geometry/order.py), but they compute the inertia tensor of the whole system while I need the inertia tensors of its parts (inertia tensor of each molecule in the system).
- It would be preferable to obtain an array of inertia tensors.
- I think that [numpy.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) would be a good alternative (but I find it hard to implement)
- I can get an array of atomic masses fast and without problems.
- If it helps, `samples` is of size 100 to 500 approx., and `atoms` up to about 20 000 (but the operation runs in many chunks that made a total of about 1E5 samples).

Comment: So your problem is vectorizing an easy to write algorithm using loops to gain performance? I would simply use a JIT compiler like numpy here. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/45403017/4045774 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/45329782/4045774